# spring controller could not retrive a data from $http angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, cors

I have a $http function in angular and a controller, but the controller do not retrieve data send from angular, in the log print

> Skip CORS processing: response already contains
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header

I have configurate my filter in `web.xml` file to the headers

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with");
```

my angular function is this

```
     app.controller('LoadCardController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.executor = function() {

        var person = {
            name : 'Prueba',
            todayDate : 1469679969827
        };

        console.log("DATA=> ", data);

        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost/myWeb/addPerson',
            data : person,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(response);

        });
    }

});
```

and my controller is this...

```
@ResponseBody
            @RequestMapping(path = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public Person addPerson(final Person person) throws CustomException {

                person.setAge("18");
                person.setBithDay("15");

                LOGGER.trace("Add person with data {}", person);

                return person;

            }

            });
        }
```

when come in controller, data of person is null, for name and todayDate attributes, that is send by me in angular.

my controller is very simple now, because only return the same person objet

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with CORS as the Spring controller is able to receive the request, as you say. Do you need to enable CORS for all hosts, at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've shown here, it seems like the request is going through, but the data isn't making it onto your `person` parameter in the Spring controller method. There could be a few different causes.

First, It could be that the request body isn't getting mapped to your Spring controller method's `person` parameter. You can tell Spring to do this automatically by using the `@RequestBody` annotation (details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)) before the method parameter. In your example:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Person addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) throws CustomException {

    person.setAge("18");
    person.setBithDay("15");

    LOGGER.trace("Add person with data {}", person);

    return person;

}
```

If that doesn't solve it, it could be a problem with the `Person` class. At the minimum, it needs to have:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String bithday;
    private Date todayDate;

    public Person() {
        // this depends how your serialization is set up
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

One convention is to use a separate data-transfer-object class (i.e. `PersonDto`), which takes the data from the request body and builds a `Person` object with it (and vice versa), so that you can control how the submission gets mapped to the backend. More info on that pattern [here](http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an option

Your DTO is

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String todayDate;
    private String age;
    private String bithDay;
 // getter and setters, etc....
```

AngularJS use:

```
// Every properties matches with your DTO, example: name, todayDate looks... 
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", 'Prueba');
formData.append("todayDate"    , '1469679969827');

console.log("DATA=> ", formData);
$http({
       method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost/myWeb/addPerson',
            data : formData,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(response);

        });
```

Your log in your browser in my case Chrome looks....

```
success
myjs.js:1744 {"data":{"name":"Prueba","todayDate":"1469679969827","age":"18","bithDay":"15"},"status":200
```